# Airflow calculate default args

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, default-arguments

I am pretty new with airflow, so I don't know if what I am trying to do, It is possible.

I have two task from the same dags. First task is using PythonOperator and its goal is to calculate some default arguments for the dag. Second task is a SqlToS3Operator which needs a calculated default args. When I execute it, I cannot get the calculated default args, so is anyway to pass them or to update default args in DAG?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you list the arguments you are trying to dynamically generate? Maybe a code example?